# Why does one project not open in C9.io but another project will open?

Tags: c9.io

When I open a particular project, it just pauses out. It wont start. But another project will open and start. Is there anyway to fix this? It has happened to me before and usually resolves itself but today it has not worked for hours. Very frustrating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I contacted them and they reset my workspace. You can check status at:

https://status.c9.io/

If they are not experiencing problems, contact support.